# Guice - "dynamic" binding?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, scope, guice

Please consider the following code snippet:

```
// some class, somewhere - CANNOT MODIFY IT
public class SystemOutPrinter implements Printer {

  private final String prefix;
  private final String suffix;

  @Inject
  public Printer(
      @Named("prefix") String prefix,
      @Named("suffix") String suffix) {
    this.prefix = prefix;
    this.suffix = suffix;
  }

  @Override
  public void print(String line) {
    System.out.println(prefix + line + suffix);
  }
}

...

// my "regular" binding, in some module
bind(Key.get(String.class, Names.named("prefix"))).toInstance("> ");
...

// runtime-provided values:
Class<? extends Printer> printerClass = SystemOutPrinter.class;
Key<String> suffixKey = Key.get(String.class, Names.named("suffix"));

// my "dynamic" binding, probably in runtime
Printer shouter = instantiate(printerClass, suffixKey, "!");
Printer asker = instantiate(printerClass, suffixKey, "?");

...

// the example usage of the above guice-injected Printers
shouter.print("test");
asker.print("test");

// the expected output:
// > test!
// > test?
```

As you see, I need to inject a global "prefix" (it is easy) and a per-instance "suffix". Usually in such scenario I would use @AssistedInject with a Factory.create(String suffix) method - but in this case, I cannot, because the SystemOutPrinter class cannot be modified. Please assume that I don't even know its source. All I get is a reference (runtime!) to a printerClass and a suffixKey and its value ("!" or "?"). At runtime, I don't even know how the binding annotation of "suffix" looks like. What I precisely need to do is implement the method:

```
public static <T> T instantiate(Class<? extends T> cls, Key<String> key, String value) {
  ...?
}
```

This is achievable by constructing a per-instance childInjector inside the instantiate() method (please assume I have the Injector instance there), but apparently this is a very expensive operation (up to MILLISECONDS, for my injector) and I cannot afford it. I was hoping it was achievable using custom scopes, but cannot get them to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not write your own factory?

```
public class SystemOutPrinterFactory {
  private final String prefix;

  public SystemOutPrinterFactory(@Named("prefix") String prefix) {
    this.prefix = prefix;
  }

  public SystemOutPrinter createWithSuffix(String suffix) {
    return new SystemOutPrinter(prefix, suffix);
  }
}
```

The `SystemOutPrinter` class is public and non-abstract with a public constructor, so this should work. The only downside is the factory needs to know the specific implementation.

If you cannot know the implementing class, then you'll need a child injector, but assuming these classes are thread-safe, you could use [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) to avoid creating the child injector more than twice.